# Laravel 4 how to submit form data to different tables

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel-4

I have an edit form where the majority of the form's data will be posted to the users table. 
For users that require a license their information will be posted to a license table, the license fields are only visible to the appropriate user type. I.E if the user type is a receptionist then they won't see the license fields but if the user type is a dentist then the fields will show etc. I have a user_id inside the license table so that I can associate the users with licenses. I set up a new eloquent model called license the majority of my work is being done in the update controller.........

**License Model**

```
class License extends Eloquent {


    protected  $table = 'temps_license';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }



}
```

**Controller**

```
public function update($id)
{

    // validate
    // read more on validation at http://laravel.com/docs/validation
    $rules = array(
        'firstname' => 'required|min:3|alpha',
        'lastname' => 'required|min:3|alpha',
        'zipcode' => 'required|min:5|numeric',
        'temp_experience' => 'required|min:1|max:50|numeric',
        'temp_travel' =>   'required|numeric',
        'temp_hourly_rate' => 'required|numeric|min:10'
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);


    // process the login
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('user/profile/' . $id . '/edit')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    } else {
        $software_checked = Input::get('software');
        if(is_array($software_checked))
        {
            $imploded_software = implode(',', $software_checked);
        }


        // store
        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->firstname       = Input::get('firstname');
        $user->lastname      = Input::get('lastname');
        $user->zipcode = Input::get('zipcode');
        $user->temp_experience = Input::get('temp_experience');
        $user->temp_travel = Input::get('temp_travel');
        $user->temp_hourly_rate = Input::get('temp_hourly_rate');
        $user->temp_software_experience = $imploded_software;
        if( $user->save() ) {
            if( $user->usertype == 'dental hygienist' && !$user->license->temp_id ) {
                $license = new License();
                $license->temp_id = $id;
                $license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');

                $license->save();
            }

                // redirect
                Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated profile!!');
                return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'');
        }
    }

}
```

**USER MODEL**

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {



    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }


    public static function getTemps()
    {

       // Create a array of allowed types.
        $types = array('dental hygienist', 'dentist', 'dental assistance');

        // Get what type the user selected.
        $type = Input::get('temptype');

        //Get user location
        //$location = Input::get('zipcode');


        // Make sure it is a valid type.
        if(!in_array($type, $types))
        {
            return App::abort(500, "Invaild temptype.");
        }

      $temps =  DB::table('users')
            ->join('availability', 'users.id', '=', 'availability.userid')
            ->select('users.id', 'users.firstname', 'users.lastname', 'users.zipcode', 'users.salary', 'availability.dateavailable')
            ->where('usertype', $type)
           //->where('zipcode', $location)
            ->get();

        return $temps;
    }

    public function license()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('License');
    }
```

**Modified Controller**

This works better but whenever i update the users date of expiration, state, or license number it works and it updates but there are duplicate entries in the database.....

```
if( $user->usertype == 'dental hygienist' || $user->usertype == 'dentist'  && !$user->license->temp_id ) {
                    $license = new License();
                    $license->user_id = $id;
                    $license->temp_id = $id;
                    $license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');
                    $license->license_number = Input::get('license_number');
                    $license->license_state = Input::get('license_state');

                    $license->save();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how you have create `User` and did you already done anything for `License` in the `user` model when you create a new user, anyways. You said you have a `type` field in `users` table and there are two types (`receptionist` `dentist`) and if type is `dentist` then they need to provide `license` data and these data will be saved in to `license` table during update of a `user` so, in you controller, you have this right now

```
$user = User::find($id);
```

In this case, I believe you have the `type` field available as `$user->type` so to determine the type of a user you can use

```
if( $user->type == 'dentist' ) {
    // save license data
}
```

But, in your `User` model you should have declared relation with `license` as

```
class User extends Eloquent {
    // ...
    public function license()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('Lisense');
    }
}
```

In your `license` model you need

```
class License extends Eloquent {
    protected  $table = 'temps_license';
    // ...
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }
}
```

So, your code should be something like this

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->firstname       = Input::get('firstname');
$user->lastname      = Input::get('lastname');
// more ...
if( $user->save() ) {
    if( $user->type == 'dentist' ) {
        $license = new License();
        $license->temp_id = $id;
        $license->license_expiration_date = Input::get('expiration_date');
        // ...
        $license->save();
    }

    Session::flash('message', 'Successfully updated profile!!');
    return Redirect::to('user/profile/'.$id.'');
}
```

There are other ways to save a related model using `push` instead of `save` but don't know more about your `User` model and relation, so this is an option for you to create `License` model depending on user type.

Comment: Thank you for the advice I updated my code to show my user model and your suggestion. I am getting an unknown column error. When I remove this line of code inside the save method !$user->license->temp_id the information saves just fine. However when I try to update the information a new record for that user is created its not updated.... The error says Unknown column 'temps_license.user_id in where clause. I think it is looking for a user_id column in the temp_license table but there is none. I associate the two tables by temp_id. I can remove it and add user_id @RCV

Comment: I've removed `&& !$user->license->temp_id`

Comment: I removed && !$user->license->temp_id and I still get the unknown column error. I modified the controller I updated my code above. This seems to work better im not getting any errors except that when I go back and change the expiration date I get two entries for the same user one showing the previous date and the other showing the new date.  @RCV

Comment: I didn't get it, it should update because you are using `:find($id)` and then `save()`, what did you mean by go back ?

Comment: It does work but when I update the license information it creates a duplicate entry in the database...... So if user_id 3 inputs their license information it saves just fine. But if user_I'd 3 updates their license expiration date than there are two different entries in the database for usrr_id  3. I think its because I am using $license = new license(); @RCV

Comment: Yes and that's why you should check first if a license with that `id` already exist and then grab it to update or insert if not available.